# Table spacing and alignment, multirow with cmidrule

Tags: tables, multirow

There is extra space between "Test column" and "wider column"/"narrow" in Column (1) and (2). I tried to get no space between the two line and align the text to the bottom by using multirow package. I could not get it work...Any ideas?

[image]

```
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}
\usepackage{multirow}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering\small
\caption{Test table}\label{table:test}
\begin{tabular}{l *{5}{d{2.4}}}
\toprule
& \mc{Test column} & \mc{Test column} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{XXXXXXX} \\
\cmidrule{4-6}
&\mc{wider column} & \mc{narrow} & \mc{AAAA} & \mc{AAAA} & \mc{AAAA} \\
& \mc{(1)} & \mc{(2)} & \mc{(3)} & \mc{(4)} & \mc{(5)} \\
\midrule
Treatment & -0.115^{***} & -0.333^{***} & -0.220^{***} & -0.573^{***} & -0.228^{**} \\ 
 & (0.005) & (0.006) & (0.006) & (0.009) & (0.009) \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution with `multirow` and `makecell`. Fine-tuning the vertical placement of the text can be made playing with the first argement (the number of lines): it can be given a fractional value.

Aldo I added the `caption` package to have a more sensible spacing between caption above and table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}
\usepackage{multirow, makecell, caption}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
\newcommand\mr[2]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{#1}{*}{\makecell{#2}}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering\small
\caption{Test table}\label{table:test}
\begin{tabular}{l *{5}{d{2.4}}}
\toprule
& \mr{2.87}{Test column\\wider column} & \mr{2.87}{Test column\\narrow} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{XXXXXXX} \\
\cmidrule(lr){4-6}
& & & \mc{AAAA} & \mc{AAAA} & \mc{AAAA} \\
& \mc{(1)} & \mc{(2)} & \mc{(3)} & \mc{(4)} & \mc{(5)} \\
\midrule
Treatment & -0.115^{***} & -0.333^{***} & -0.220^{***} & -0.573^{***} & -0.228^{**} \\
 & (0.005) & (0.006) & (0.006) & (0.009) & (0.009) \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!!! I also would like to align the text to (1) and (2), so "wider column" and "narrow" in the same line as AAAA. Any thoughts?

Comment: That's what you had with your code. Do you mean you want the ‘Test column’ a little lower than ‘XXXXXXX’, and the second line aligned with ‘AAAA’?

Comment: Yes! Sorry for not being clear. I hope to have both lines aligned to the bottom (so narrow stays and test column comes down)

Comment: It's easy: we can use fractional values with `\multirow`, so by trial and error, using `\mr{2.85}` instead of `\mr{2}` does the job.

Comment: Thanks! Playing with it. May I ask why we need \multicolumn{1}{c} before multirow? We are not merging any columns here?

Comment: No, but there seems to be a problem with `dcolumn` (which I don't know well): I first tried without \multicolumn, and the two lines were typed in math mode. It's what I found to have the content of the command in text mode. Note I don't think we would have this problem with `siunitx`.

Comment: Thanks! I tried. 2.87 did not work for me, it puts .87 as text in front of Test Column. However, I entered 3 and it worked. This is very strange as technically we still have 2 rows here... Also a mystery to why need \multicolumn -- I spent so much time playing with \siunitx and \dcolumn, the conclusion was that for what I need (align decimals, good space for stars, and center number in text with commas), all together, siunitx does not work well... Here is the link: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/440238/font-type-for-math-in-non-math-mode-number-font-consistency-within-table

Comment: Do you have a recent version of multirow? I used version 2.2, which dates back to November 2017.

Comment: No idea... I use Texpad and it suppose update all packages regularly?

Comment: No idea. What is your distribution?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution I just figured out... I replaced `\cmidrule` by `\cline`, and the spacing between XXXXX and AAAA disappeared, so no need to adjust spacing for (1) and (2). Just an alternative way...

Comment: Yes, but the rules from booktabs have some vertical padding which makes them look nicer.

Answer (score 1):

My idea is to smash the two row cells:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{caption}

\NewDocumentCommand{\tworowcell}{m}{%
  \smash[b]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\tn}{m}{\ensuremath{{}^{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\caption{Test table}\label{table:test}

\sisetup{
  table-format=-1.3,
  table-space-text-post={\tn{***}},
  input-symbols={()},
}
\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-0.5pt}

\begin{tabular}{ @{} l *{5}{S} @{} }
\toprule
& \tworowcell{Test column \\ wider column}
& \tworowcell{Test column \\ narrow }
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{XXXXXXX} \\
\cmidrule(l){4-6}
& & & {AAAA} & {AAAA} & {AAAA} \\
& {(1)} & {(2)} & {(3)} & {(4)} & {(5)} \\
\midrule
Treatment & -0.115\tn{***} & -0.333\tn{***} & -0.220\tn{***} & -0.573\tn{***} & -0.228\tn{**} \\ 
 & (0.005) & (0.006) & (0.006) & (0.009) & (0.009) \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You can also use `dcolumn`, but then `\tworowcell` should be encapsulated in a `\multicolumn{1}{c}`.

[image]